# Changing the foreground color of sub-elements of selected rows in Qt5.4

Tags: c++, qt, qstylesheet

I would like to change the foreground color of cell widgets in a `QTableWidget`. The hierarchy is the following:

```
QTableWidget
> QTableWidgetItem[]
>> QLabel
>> QLineEdit
>> QLineEdit
>> QLineEdit
>> QLineEdit
```

That is, five columns and `N` rows in a list view. I want the font color of all sub-items to change when a row is selected/highlighted. I am trying to obtain this using `QStyleSheet`.

**Attempts**

1) The following does not work, because it changes the color regardless of the selection state:

```
QTableWidget::item:selected QLabel,
QTableWidget::item:selected QLineEdit {
color: white;
}
```

2) The following does not work, because `QLabel`/`QLineEdit` does not respond to `selection-color`:

```
QTableWidget::item:selected QLabel,
QTableWidget::item:selected QLineEdit {
color: #666;
selection-color: white;
}
```